# Transformar array multidimensional em unidimensional em VUE

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou precisando transformar um array multidimensional em VUE em um array unidimensional, pois preciso recupera um array apenas com os campos "cod" dessa array, tendei da forma abaixo sem sucesso.

```
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data : {
        array_teste : [{cod : '1', nome : 'S'},{cod : '2', nome : 'V'}],
    },

    computed: {
        cat_vender_rec: function() {
            return JSON.stringify(this.cat_vender);
        }
    }       
})
```

Comment: Só lembrando que você não tem um array multi-dimensional aí... Você tem um array de objetos com dimensão 1.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método `.map()` para mapear os dados do array que você quer.

```
const array = [{cod : '1', nome : 'S'},{cod : '2', nome : 'V'}];

const arrayCods = array.map(obj => {
  return obj.cod;    
});

console.log(arrayCods); // ['1', '2']
```

[Documentação do método .map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)